# How to hide/reveal different actions on the same FloatingActionButton like in Inbox app

Tags: java, android, android-animation, floating-action-button

Is there any way to animate the icon in a `FloatingActionButton` from the support library? I want to animate it like in the Inbox app, where it transforms from a `plus` to a `pencil` when you click it.

Comment: The best way to to do that would probably be using an `AnimatedVectorDrawable` but that isn't backwards compatible before 5.0. I normally just put two `FloatingActionButton`s on top of each other and then fade out the top one while rotating both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to to do that would probably be using an `AnimatedVectorDrawable` but that isn't backwards compatible before 5.0. I normally just put two `FloatingActionButton`s on top of each other and then fade out the top one while rotating both.

As an example you can put two `FloatingActionButton`s into a `FrameLayout` like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end|right">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@id/fab_edit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_edit"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_add"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

The bottom `FloatingActionButton` in the `FrameLayout` will be on top of the other one. You can then rotate and fade out the bottom one and at the same time just rotate the top one to create an animation similar to the animation in Google apps which will reveal the top one. For example you can implement the animation like this:

```
// This animation rotates and hides the top Button
final Animator hideTopFabAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(fabAdd,
        PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.ALPHA, 1.0f, 0.0f),
        PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.ROTATION, 0.0f, 360.0f)
);

// This animation just rotates the bottom Button while it is being revealed
final Animator revealBottomFabAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(fabEdit,
        PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.ROTATION, 0.0f, 360.0f)
);

// This AnimatorSet combines both animations and also has a listener 
// attached to set the visibility of the top Button to View.GONE when
// the animation is done so the user can actually click through to the 
// lower Button
final AnimatorSet revealAnimation = new AnimatorSet();
revealAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
revealAnimation.playTogether(
        hideTopFabAnimation,
        revealBottomFabAnimation
);
revealAnimation.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
        fabAdd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
revealAnimation.start();
```

And to go back to the original state you just have to do the reverse:

```
// Set the visibility of the top Button back to VISIBLE
fabAdd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

// This animation fades the top Button back in and rotates it back
final Animator showTopFabAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(fabAdd,
        PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.ALPHA, 0.0f, 1.0f),
        PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.ROTATION, 360.0f, 0.0f)
);

// This animation just rotates the bottom Button while the top Button 
// fades back in
final Animator hideBottomFabAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(fabEdit,
        PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.ROTATION, 360.0f, 0.0f)
);

// Again we have an AnimatorSet which plays both animations together
final AnimatorSet hideAnimation = new AnimatorSet();
revealAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
revealAnimation.playTogether(
        showTopFabAnimation,
        hideBottomFabAnimation
);
revealAnimation.start();
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunally, putting the FABs inside a FrameLayout inside a CoordinatorLayout will not display them in the bottom right corner, but in the top left corner

Comment: @qwertz Look at the layout in my answer. I set the `layout_gravity` to `bottom|end|right|` which is the backwards compatible way of saying that you want the `FrameLayout` to be positioned on the bottom right.

Comment: @qwertz Is your problem solved? Is there something else I can do to help you?

Comment: sorry, was really busy the last few days. Your code works fine, fixed the issue with the fab being in the left corner, thanks :)